# How can I apply a filters to ONE image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit, cifilter

I'm beginner in Swift and make an app "Photo Editor". I have a problem. I need to apply a some filters to ONE image. I have four sliders(sepia, contrast, brightness, saturation ) and one image. I want to apply all this filters to my image.

I try to change my logic in code, but I have the same problem

```
@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider!) 

    if sender.tag == 0 {
            let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
            let value = sender.value
            self.sepiaLabelValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
            if  let sepiaCIImage = sepiaFilter(originalCIImage!, intensity: Double(value)) {
                filteredImage = sepiaCIImage
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: sepiaCIImage)
            }

        } else if sender.tag == 1 {
            let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
            let value = sender.value
            self.brightnessValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
            if let brightnessCIImage = brightnessFilter(originalCIImage!, intensity: Double(value)) {
                filteredImage = brightnessCIImage
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage:brightnessCIImage)
            }

        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
            let value = sender.value
            self.contrastLabel.text = String(Int(value*100))
            let contrastCIImage = contrastFilter(originalCIImage!, intensity: Double(value))
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage:contrastCIImage!)

        } else if sender.tag == 3 {
            let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
            let value = sender.value
            self.saturationValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
            let saturationCIImage = saturationFilter(originalCIImage!, intensity: Double(value))
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage:saturationCIImage!)
        }
}


func sepiaFilter(_ input: CIImage, intensity: Double) -> CIImage?
    {
        let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name:"CISepiaTone")
        sepiaFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        sepiaFilter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        return sepiaFilter?.outputImage
    }

    func brightnessFilter(_ input: CIImage, intensity: Double) -> CIImage? {
        let brightnessFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        brightnessFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        brightnessFilter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
        return brightnessFilter?.outputImage
    }

    func contrastFilter(_ input: CIImage, intensity: Double) -> CIImage? {
        let contrastFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        contrastFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        contrastFilter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
        return contrastFilter?.outputImage
    }

    func saturationFilter(_ input: CIImage, intensity: Double) -> CIImage? {
        let saturationFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        saturationFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        saturationFilter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
        return saturationFilter?.outputImage
    }
```

When I apply first filter and then next filter, the value of first filter is established to begin state. How can I apply all filters to my image?

Comment: Use `switch` instead of `else if`. It’s easier to understand and works the same.

Comment: Okey. I changed this, but it doesn't resolve my problem(((

Comment: You must chain the filters. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html

Comment: Okey, thanks for information!
But it's hard for me, because I don't know, how it apply to my code. I understood the general sense of the chain, but I don’t know how to rewrite the code

Answer (score 1):

As Gigi said, the trick is to always apply both filters to the image when a value changed. This should do the trick:

```
let colorControlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name:"CISepiaTone")!


@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider!) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0: 
        let value = sender.value
        self.sepiaLabelValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
        self.sepiaFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
    case 1:
        let value = sender.value
        self.brightnessValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    case 2:
        let value = sender.value
        self.contrastLabel.text = String(Int(value*100))
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
    case 3:
        let value = sender.value
        self.saturationValue.text = String(Int(value*100))
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
    default: pass
    }

    self.updateImage()
}

func updateImage() {
    let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
    // first apply color controls (contrast, brightness, saturation), then sepia
    self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(originalCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    self.sepiaFilter.setValue(self.colorControlsFilter.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: self.sepiaFilter.outputImage!)
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can I apply this filters, but instead of "sepia" filter use a kCIInputSharpnessKey, because I want create a new View Controller, where will be only filters like "sepia". But on this View Controller I want leave only a standart filters such as "contrast", "brightness" and so on.

Comment: Sure, you can replace any of the filters as you like. As long as you "chain" them in `updateImage` (use the output of one filter as the input of the next), it should work.

Comment: Okey. But how I can initialize a sharpness filter as you initialized a sepia filter.
let sharp = CIFilter(name: "kCIInputSharpnessKey")!
It doesn't work((

Comment: `kCIInputSharpnessKey` is not a filter name, but the name of the sharpness parameter used by some filters. What you are looking for is the `CISharpenLuminance` filter: https://cifilter.io/CISharpenLuminance/

Comment: Hello! I have a problem with work of my app. May be do you know, how to fixe it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092349/sliders-slow-down-and-dont-move-smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)      
  if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone") {
                    let beginImage = CIImage(image: image!)
                    currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                    
                    
                    if let output = currentFilter.outputImage {
                        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                            filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
                        }
               }
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your code.