# sliders slow down and don't move smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uislider

I'm doing an application "Photo Editor". I'm beginner in swift. I have a problem with my sliders. They don't work as I need. May be someone know, how I can resolve this problem?

Sliders don't work correctly and I need help with it. I don't know, why it's work like that.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerFilters: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var image: UIImage? = nil
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
var filteredImage: CIImage? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
let context = CIContext()

@IBOutlet weak var slider2: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var slider3: UISlider!

@IBOutlet weak var slider4: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.imageView.image = image
    self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged )
    self.slider2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.slider3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.slider4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)


}


let colorControlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name:"CISepiaTone")!
let sharp = CIFilter(name: "CISharpenLuminance")!




@objc func sliderValueDidChange(sender: UISlider!) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        let value = sender.value
        self.sharp.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputSharpnessKey)
    case 1:
        let value = sender.value
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    case 2:
        let value = sender.value
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
    case 3:
        let value = sender.value
        self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(value, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
    default:
        print("no such elements")
    }

    self.updateImage()
}

func updateImage() {
    let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
    self.colorControlsFilter.setValue(originalCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    self.sharp.setValue(self.colorControlsFilter.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: self.sharp.outputImage!)

}
```

I need a smoothly moving of my sliders, because it's impossible to work with it.

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow. what do you mean by not smooth? is it laggy?

Comment: yes. The moving of sliders comes in maybe 5 seconds after my mouse click

Comment: comment `self.updateImage()` in `sliderValueDidChange` function. If the problem is solved, probably you should revise that function since it is heavy in case of allocating resources.

Comment: okey. It solved this problem, but it function is very important, and if it comment the code it doesn't work as I need. Where I can revise my function?

Comment: Creating a `CIImage` from `UIImage` may require extra time to copy the image data from memory to GPU memory.

Comment: define your `originalCIImage` somewhere outside of this function since it is constant and check if it works.

Comment: no, the same problem again...

Comment: Are you testing on Simulator? It's not very good with image processing performance and you should always test on device. Aside from that you can try to wrape the code inside `updateImage` inside block like this: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { <code here> }`. This will perform the operations in the block in on a background there which prevents blocking the UI.

Comment: Okey. I did like that.
func updateImage() {
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image!)
               ...  }  }
But now the app doesn't work correctly and also there're a warning "UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only

Answer (score -1):

you will receive valueChanged event only when the user stops moving the slider.

```
slider.isContinuous = false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).